# How to rotate binary trees on disk

Tags: sorting, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm designing an on-disk only avl tree library.

Each node of the tree is as follows.

```
struct node 
{
   int key;
   unsigned char height;
   int64 left;
   int64 right;
};
```

and each node when created is saved into a file.

The left and right fields are an offset into the file
 where the left and right child nodes reside.

So far all works fine, except when it comes to tree rotations.

if nodes were in memory the rotation is as follows.

```
node* rotateright(node* p)
{
   node* q = p->left;
   p->left = q->right;
   q->right = p;
   fixheight(p);
   fixheight(q);
   return q;
}
```

However, I'm using offsets into a file instead of memory.

```
int64 rotateright(int64 p)
{
  node q_node;
  node p_node;

  seek(fp,p*sizeof(node));
  read(fp,sizeof(node),&p_node);

  seek(fp,p.left*sizeof(node));
  read(fp,sizeof(node),&q_node);

  p.left=q_node.right;

  // etc...
}
```

I can't get this function working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Disk is not an appropriate medium for AVL trees, because:

1) You can't read just a little bit of data from disk.  You'll always get at least a sector, and you can get a little more pretty much for free; and

2) Reading from an arbitrary position on disk is very expensive.

For these reasons, disk-based search trees (used for database indexes, for example) use different data structures.  The B+ tree is common:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

You should do something like that instead.

Finding an item with a disk-based AVL tree will take about 10 times as many accesses as finding it with a B+ tree.